# Replace string that is separated by whitespace or other special character in PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to find a way to find part of the string in text and to replace it with ***

For example, I have text `"Jumping fox jumps around the box"`
in normal cases, I would use:

> preg_replace('/\b(fox)\b/i', '****', "fox");

but I want to cover cases when we have text `"Jumping f.o.x jumps around the box"`
or `"Jumping f o x jumps around the box"`

So basically, I would need regex to support that kind of searches... to cover more special characters is even better

Comment: Then use `'/\bf\W*o\W*x\b/i'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add the class of to be ignored chars between each char of the search string. This could  be done with simple php functions

```
$string = 'Jumping f.o.x jumps around the box';
$word = 'fox';
$ignore = '[\s\.]*';
$regex = '/\b' . join($ignore, str_split($word)) . '\b/i';
$new_string = preg_replace($regex, '***', $string);
```

If your word contains some regex special chars, you might want to apply `preg_quote` to each char.

```
join($ignore, array_map(function($char) {
    return preg_quote($char, '/');
}, str_split($word)));
```

Comment: Not bad. What would be regex to include  _ or - in this part?

Comment: just add the chars to the ignore class `[\s\._-]` (keep in mind, `-` has a special meaning and have to be escaped or placed at the end/beginning)

Comment: Got it... 
I have issue when f.o.x is f.ox or fo.x (can be another char as well), could you help me with that?

Comment: replace the `+` with an `*`

Answer (score 0):

This is final function.

```
if (! function_exists('preg_replace_word')) {

    function preg_replace_word($search, $replace, $string)
    {
        $ignore = '[\s\._-]*';
        $regex = '/\b' . join($ignore, str_split($search)) . '\b/i';
        return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
    }
}
```